# store pointer to words in sentence

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have run across a problem where, when storing pointers to characters in a sentence into a new array, if I add a '\0' character to the sentence to split up the words the program ends early, but if I do not add that character then the new array stores too many words.

```
   int prevSpace = 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < (strlen(sentence)); i++){
       if(sentence[i] != ' ' && prevSpace == 1){
          prevSpace = 0;
          List[j] = &sentence[i];
          printf("list[%d] now points to %c\n", j, sentence[i]);
          j++;
       }

       if(sentence[i] != ' '){
           prevSpace = 0;
       }

       if(sentence[i] == ' '){
           /*if we find space and last char was not a space, add '\0'
           if(prevSpace == 0){
              printf("end added\n");
              sentence[i] = '\0';        /**** <<<FOCUS ON THIS LINE! */
           }

           prevSpace = 1;
       }
   }

   /*finish List with NULL*/
   List[j] = NULL;


   /*print out list of words*/
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      printf("List[%d] = %s\n", i, List[i]);
   }
```

The problem with this code is, instead of the array list having each word, it has only the first word, then many nulls. For the sentence "test one two three", the output is:

```
list[0] now points to t

List[0] = test
List[1] = (null)
List[2] = (null)
List[3] = (null)
```

If I change that important line to    line[i] = 'X';

then output for the sentence "test one two three" is:

```
list[0] now points to t
list[1] now points to o
list[2] now points to t
list[3] now points to t

List[0] = testX  oneX  twoX  three
List[1] = oneX  twoX  three
List[2] = twoX  three
List[3] = three
```

but this is bad because I want list[0] to only have "test", list[1] to only have "one", list[2] to only have "two", and list[3] to only have "three". I need a way through this so that I can use the end of string character '\0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to leave everything inside `string[]` and not copy things into `list[]`. You have a problem with your `for` loop because it will recheck `strlen[string]` and after you add the  `\0` you have cut short `string` so the loop will stop.

I don't know how you are handling memory, but it would be better to have something like

```
char word[50][50]  //choose the values to suit - 1st is max words, 
                   //  2nd is max length of word

int i, j, k; 
//new loop
for(i = 0, j=0,k=0; i < (strlen(sentence)); i++, k++)
{
  word[j][k]=string[i];
  if (word[j][k]=' ')
  {
     word[j][k]=0;
     j++; k=0;  // to move to next word 
  }
}
```

this code should be all you need to put words from sentence into the 2D array word[][]

Comment: Oh my gosh that makes so much sense now. I made a variable "length" and used that for the loop and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @SJiles great glad it worked - you could try the code above which does things a little differently and moves words from sentence into a new array.... but glad it is working for you